# Is it possible that the APK installed from outside Google Play can be updated without any popup?

Tags: android

My customer wants to develop a application which can be updated without any interaction from users.
This application will be installed from outside Google Play. Of course, `unknown source` in Android setting menu will be set when it is installed.

I think it will be updated automatically without user interaction if it is installed from Google Play. But, it is installed from outside Google Play, automatic update might not be allowed because of security issues.
But, my customer wants to find the solution of this issue.

Is it possible? If not, how can I find the basis that it is impossible such as any official or authoritative document?

In addition, if my customer receives any support from the manufacturer of the Android device which the application is installed, is the automatic update possible?

Comment: No, It is not possible without user interaction unless you use Samsung KNOX SDK or Android Enterprise for B2B solution.

Comment: Thank you, Chirag. I will study Android Enterprise for B2B solution as your advice.